# Convert amount column to Indian rupees with comma separated in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that, I need to convert the amount column which is decimal data type to below required output format in SQL

```
Amount: 50000000.00
Output: 5,00,00,000
```

Please help me on this

```
Select replace(convert(varchar,convert(money,50000000),1),’.00’,’’)
```

Comment: Why do that in SQL? Much easier in your application code.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with the [Numeric Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString) set to use Indian English culture (`en-IN`) and zero decimal position (`N0`).

Thus,

```
select format (50000000,'N0', 'en-IN')
```